# node.js async.each() callback was called before all iteration was finished

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Can somebody explain me how I can to do callback only after all iteration was finished? I used async.each function for that:

```
async.each(products, function (product, callback) {
    fs.appendFile('ParseLog.txt', "PRODUCT name: " + product.name, function (err) {
        console.log("iterate");
        callback();
    });
}, function (err) {
    console.log("ALL FINISH");
});
```

So my input looks like:

```
ALL FINISH 
iterate 
iterate
iterate
...
```

but I expect that "ALL FINISH" message will prints AFTER all iteration.
**EDIT 1:**
Sorry but it seems trouble was in  `if(i > 10)  return callback({ data: 'hi'}); // stop` at start of each loop.
I just want to exit after 11 iteration, but it stranges to me why its do callback at first.?

```
 async.each(products, function (product, callback) {
    var i = products.indexOf(product);
    if(i > 10)  return callback({ data: 'hi'}); // stop
 fs.appendFile('ParseLog.txt', "PRODUCT name: " + product.name, function (err) {
            console.log("iterate");
            callback();
        });
..
```

Comment: Yes you can use promises to do that

Comment: Is the code that you're using the _exact_ code that you're posting here? I don't see how it can cause what you're seeing.

Comment: sorry, my blame see my updates

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should limit the number of products to process *before* you pass it into `async.each`:

```
async.each(products.slice(0, 11), function (product, callback) {
  fs.appendFile('ParseLog.txt', "PRODUCT name: " + product.name, function (err) {
    console.log("iterate");
    callback(err); // make sure to pass `err`!
  });
}, function(err) {
  if (err) console.log('ERROR', err);
  console.log("ALL FINISH");
});
```

Also, when you call a continuation callback, the first argument is "reserved" to signal that an error occurred. In your example, you're using it to pass an object (`{ data: 'hi' }`) which will make `async` think that an error happened (unless that was your intention?). The proper idiom is this:

```
callback(null, { data: 'hi' })
```

Comment: thx.
(unless that was your intention?). yep I use error throwing only after 11 iteration for break the cycle. But it strange to me why its throw it on first iteration

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack It *is* on the last iteration. The iterations will all completely dispatch before the first `fs.appendFile` callback completes, though. Add a `console.log("iteration dispatched");` to the top of your `function (product, callback)` function to see this. Maybe you actually want `async.eachSeries` which will wait until the current iteration completes before dispatching the next iteration.

Comment: thx, got it.So eachSeries its like synchronous version of each.

Comment: @MeetJoeBlack `eachSeries` is the _sequential_ version of `each`